# Alternative to Relative Protocol for Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, relative-path

So Chrome is not wanting to honor relative protocol. What is a good alternative. I am thinking about using PHP to sniff out the protocol and use a constant. Good idea?

Comment: Can you provide evidence that it doesn't work?  I'm using this in production in several places, and am not having trouble at the moment.  Perhaps it's my version?

Comment: the site is www.reflectionproducts.com. Specifically during the checkout phase, after putting any item in the cart. The CSS is not loading for relative paths but is loading for the file i directly put https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Chrome.  Your server is redirecting your HTTPS CSS requests to HTTP.

Go to `https://www.reflectionproducts.com/FC_CSS.css`.  You'll get a 301 permanent redirect to `http://www.reflectionproducts.com/FC_CSS.css`.

Chrome does indeed allow usage of URLs that do not specify protocol.

Comment: Takes a second set of eyes sometimes.